# vertical align CSS property

Tags: css, vertical-alignment

This might seem like a pretty simple problem but it has managed to stump me so far. The vertical align property works correctly for me. However, when I add a 
 tag after the text that I want to run along the center of the image, any text after the 
 tag displays directly underneath the image.

Example:

```
<img src="test.png" width="50" height="50" alt="test" style="vertical-align:middle;"/>        This text is fine. <br />This text is not.
```

Comment: can you close the <img> tag after the text? So <img src="test.png" width="50" height="50" alt="test" style="vertical-align:middle;">        This text is fine. <br />This text is not.</img>   ?

Comment: Just tried it. It doesn't work :(

Comment: check if this works for you: http://jsfiddle.net/jpLcY/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
<img src="test.png" width="50" height="50" alt="test" style="vertical-align:middle;"/>        

<div style='display:inline-block; vertical-align:top;'> 
    <span style='display:inline-block;vertical-align:middle;'>This text is fine. <br />This text is not.
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Your example contains the tag `<br />`, which by definition means a line break.

Comment: I understand. But, is there anyway that all of the text could be aligned to the middle instead of just the first line?

Answer (score 0):

Here the best way to align center almost everything in CSS.

```
.centrado-vertical{
  position: relative;
  top: 50%;
  -webkit-transform: translateY(-50%);
  -ms-transform: translateY(-50%);
  transform: translateY(-50%);
}
```